# Cosmos Db stored procedure RU charge is higher than equivalent query via sdk or portal?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it expected that a query executed via a stored proc has a higher RU charge (almost double), than that of the same query executed via the sdk or portal?

This test code shows both cases execute a query for a single document against partitionKey and document id.

#### Simple query executed via stored proc

Simple stored proc to test execution of a single document by id. As this is executed withing the scope of a single partition, it should result in a direct query against partition and doc id.

```
function testProc(id, props) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    // Validate input.
    if (!id) throw new Error("The id is undefined or null.");
    if (!props) throw new Error("The update is undefined or null.");

    tryQuery();

    function tryQuery() {
         var query = {query: "select * from root r where r.id = @id", parameters: [{name: "@id", value: id}]};

         var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
             if (err) throw err;

             if (documents.length == 1) {
                 // Update props
             } else {
                 // Else a document with the given id does not exist..
                 throw new Error("Document not found.");
             }
         });

         // If we hit execution bounds - throw an exception.
         // This is highly unlikely given that this is a query by id; but is included to serve as an example for larger queries.
         if (!isAccepted) {
             throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out.");
         }
     }
}
```

**Request Charge:** 5.68 RU

#### Query direct in the portal

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.partitionKey = 'Tenant_8_u768f5c6b-ef6d-4cd9-8ad0-ae0c68eb9887@mail.com' and c.id = 'c12a3dbd-ad19-41d6-971b-79e0c7acec41'
```

**Request Charge:** 2.890 RUs

I can only assume according to the [cosmos request units and throughput documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) that this discrepancy comes about due to the physical overhead of compute resources (cpu / memory) required in order to run the stored proc itself.

For a simple query to pull out a document by partition and id it seems rather high though.

Comment: Have you tried running a version of your stored procedure with no validation / error checking, to see if that is adding to your RU cost? Also - fyi since you know the ID you're searching for, a direct read (via SDK call) will cost less than the equivalent query.

Comment: As indicated this was a test I put together when I noticed something was off with with a more complicated stored procedure that goes on to do additional work and update the document. But I noticed the just reading the doccument in the stored procedure seems to cost almost double that of querying it directly. I'll try commenting out most of the validation and see if the RU cost goes down at all.

Comment: With validation disabled there was no observable difference in RU cost of the stored proc. Interestingly though, the RU cost keeps changing from execution to execution on retrieval of different docs. What would cause this? I thought the RU charge should be the same on the same query executed over almost identical docs of the same size. Also, you mention that the SDK call for a query *will* cost less than the equivalent query in the stored proc? Why is that?

Comment: I can't explain the variation you're seeing. But... point-reads don't follow the same path as the general query engine. There's documentation somewhere about it, but... general rule is something like 1RU for a 1K document via Read (something not achievable via query).

Comment: This isn't a query on alternate indexed paths though that I would expect would invoke a more expensive query op (4x more expensive according to the same M$ docs). In this case both the stored proc and portal / sdk query generate a query direct to the partition and document id lookup.The stored proc executes within the context of a single partition with a direct lookup to document id also. I appreciate your help and feedback on these cosmos questions as it's often difficult to get answers.